# Geometrical construction of triangle

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to draw an equilateral triangle, inscribed into an obtuse 120° triangle in such a way that each vertex of the equilateral triangle lies on each side of the external triangle?

I know it is possible because I have made a drawing but I don't know how to do the construction.
Any ideas are most welcome!

Comment: By construction, do you mean, ruler-and-compass construction?

Comment: Construct a small equilateral triangle near the big angle, with two vertices on the sides of that angle and the third in the interior.  The figure you want can then be constructed by similarity.

Comment: @lulu: but if I "grow" the small triangle, then its vertices will not be on the sides! It will grow uniformly from all 3 vertices!

Comment: Grow it from the corner of the big angle. That way the two vertices 'stay' on the sides and the third one will eventually 'hit' the opposite side.

Comment: @MariusStephant   No it won't.  draw the line $L$ from the given vertex through the suspended point $P$ out to the third side.  That's one point on your triangle.  Now clone the angles made by your small triangle at $P$ by $L$.  That gives you two rays and those point to the other two vertices of your desired triangle.

Comment: @lulu: can you upload a draft sketch?

Comment: No time now, though perhaps someone else here can.  [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/InscribedSquare.shtml#explanation) is the same technique applied to constructing a square instead of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @lulu Theoretically yes. By "growing" the initial equilateral continually, we can get the required but the question is  "what is the stopping criteria?"

Comment: @Mick  What do you mean?  I stop when the free vertex is on the opposing side.  The convexity of the interior implies that the family of similar equilateral triangles stay in the interior until the free vertex touches.

Comment: The $120^o$ angle seems to do no work here.  In fact, I think you can join any two points on adjacent sides of any angle in any triangle, and construct an equilateral triangle on one of the parallels to that line which will have its vertices on the sides of the given triangle.

Comment: @lulu If the 1st one drawn is not large enough to reach the opposite side, we try to “grow” a bigger one and “hope” (or more simply “guess”) that it is the one. If not, we continue the ‘guessing’ process. The target (i.e. the third vertex) will be reached theoretically. My question is … can we define (in terms of some suitable parameters) the stopping condition instead of guessing or approximating?

Comment: @Mick  I have no idea what you mean.  If the vertex is $V$ and the suspended point of the small triangle is $P$ then you construct the ray $\vec {VP}$ and extend it until it meets the side opposite $V$.  Thus we have constructed the point $Q$ which is one vertex of the desired triangle.  there is no "hope" or "guess" involved.

Comment: @lulu That is exact what I mean. A method of finding V is needed instead of growing triangles indefinitely.

Comment: @Mick  But of course $V$ is given, it is a vertex of the original triangle.

Answer (score 1):

[image: equilateral triangle]Triangle $ABC$ has the $120^o$ angle at $A$.  Take $D$, $E$ anywhere on $AC$, $AB$, join $DE$ and construct equilateral triangle $DEF$ (Euclid I, 1). Join $AF$, and let $G$ be its intersection with $BC$. Through $G$ draw $GH$, $GK$ parallel to $FD$, $FE$, and join $HK$.

Since triangle $HKG$ is similar to triangle $DEF$, it is also equilateral, and it has its vertices on the sides of triangle $ABC$.

If $D$, $E$ are chosen so that $\triangle DEF$ is too large for $\triangle ABC$, the same method will shrink it to the right size.

Comment: Referring to your comment, I think the $120^0$ has no bearing on this question. The same construction works for all cases of $60^0 \le \angle BAC \lt 180^0$. However, it will give an add-on effect of ADFE and AHGK being cyclic.